# If $M$ positive definite is a sum $B+B^T$, then $B$ is nonsingular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to prove that if $M$ is a positive definite matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ that is equal to $B + B^T$, then the matrix $B$ is nonsingular.

Obviously, $M$ is symmetric, so I tried to diagonalise it (orthogonally), to get $D=Q^{T}BQ+QB^TQ^T$. Then the two matrices on the right are transposes of each other and similar to $B$, so I reduced the problem to trying to show that $C$ is nonsingular if $D=C+C^T$, $D$ diagonal. Positive definiteness of $M$ implies that the eigenvalues on the diagonal of $D$ are all positive, so $C$ must have positive diagonal entries, and its upper and lower triangular parts are negative mirror images of each other.

But I'm stuck now. I tried the permutation formula of the determinant but couldn't come up with a proof. Is there something obvious that I'm missing, some way to use the positive definite condition?

Thanks

Comment: Try to prove by contradiction: if $B$ is singular then there exists $v$ such that $Bv = 0$. What happens to $v^T(B + B^T)v$ then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove that, it is easier to prove the contrapositive, that is, proving that $B$ singular implies that $B+B^T$ is not positive definite. Let $v\ne 0$ be such that $Bv=0$, then we have that $v^T(B+B^T)v=0$, proving that the matrix $B+B^T$ is not positive definite.